# How to run groovy script on ubuntu start?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm want to execute the script once the machine is up and running.
Basically running "groovy /scripts/myscript.groovy".

No need for it to be a service or to re-run the script in case it's stopped!

2 questions:

- Where should I put that call? rc.local? init.d? excuse my ubuntu (lack of) skills.
- Is there a way I can test it other than restarting the machine? (Amazon EC2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lYou right, you have to create a new line on rc.local or create a script (start/stop/restart/status) in /etc/init.d/myscript.

Ex on rc.local call :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# ....
#
/path/to/groovy /path/to/your/scripts/myscript.groovy
exit 0
```

And about boot, you can have all informations on /var/log/boot.log on each boot. On try uptime to test the uptime of your server. Or add one more rc.local line to call a script who warn you by mail if the server boot, etc. There is many possibilities, depending of your needs.